# Uploading multiple content to Cloudinary React js

Tags: reactjs, axios, cloudinary

I'm building this website where users can sometimes upload one audio or one image and sometimes both at the same time to cloudinary. **I'm able to upload from the front-end (react.js) one or the other (image or audio) but not both at the same time.**

I saw [this post](https://support.cloudinary.com/hc/en-us/articles/202520662-How-can-I-bulk-upload-my-images-) that says that it is not possible except if we "write a script and use multi-threads (up to 10 threads) to upload many files at once. " I have no idea what it means in the context of react.js | JavaScript.

My code is the following:

I first call the `handleUploadCloudinary` with its parameter. The function is being called once the data is ready to be published.

```
  const publishTheEntry = () => {
    const {
      mainText,
      mediaAudio,
      mediaImg
    } = formData;

    if(mediaAudio !== ""){
      handleUploadCloudinary("audio");
    };
     if(mediaImg !== ""){
      handleUploadCloudinary("image");
    };
  };
```

The `handleUploadCloudinary()` is the following:

```
const handleUploadCloudinary = (mediaType) => {

    const {
      mediaAudio,
      mediaImg
    } = formData;

    const formDataCloudinary = new FormData();  
    formDataCloudinary.append("upload_preset", my_var_here);
    formDataCloudinary.append("timestamp", (Date.now() / 1000) | 0);

    if(mediaType === "img"){

      formDataCloudinary.append("file", mediaImg);
      axios.post(
        "https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/sismographie-cloud/image/upload", 
        formDataCloudinary
      ).then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
        let url = response.data.secure_url;
        setFormData({...formData, mediaImg: url});
      })  

    }else if(mediaType === "audio"){

      formDataCloudinary.append("file", mediaAudio); 
      axios.post(
        "https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/sismographie-cloud/upload", 
        formDataCloudinary
      ).then((response) => {
        let url = response.data.secure_url;
        setFormData({...formData, mediaAudio: url});
      }) 

    }
  };
```

Even if, for when both audio + image are stored into the state, I can console.log() both of the conditions, the state won't bot update the `formData` with both. One will successfully sate the state with a new cloudinary link while the other one will remain a buffer.

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through your resources list and upload assets one by one, or create new threads at the backend (best practice).

This link is a demo for uploading multiple files using Axios and React:
https://codesandbox.io/s/chunked-client-side-upload-forked-vqx6mp?file=/src/CldCustUploadLgRestApi.js